# Pyglet unstable frame rate

Tags: python, opengl, animation, pyglet

I am trying to create a simple program in Pyglet that shows an animation and retrieves some mouse input and saves it to a text file. The code I have shows a significant unstable frame rate even when I am not using the mouse.

I have also looked at similar questions and the answers suggest to use a subclassed window, or to call the function `on_draw` with `schedule_interval`. I do not know, however, how to use a subclassed window to display my animation and, when I try to call `on_draw` with `schedule_interval` I get the error that `on_draw` does not receives any argument.

This is part of the code I am using:

```
fps = pyglet.clock.ClockDisplay()# Show FPS

@mywindow.event
def on_mouse_press(x, y, button, modifiers):
    global timeStart, file, count
    timeNow = time.clock() - timeStart

    if button == mouse.LEFT:
        print('left click press in {}').format(timeNow)
        with open(out_file_name, 'a') as file:
            file.write(str(count) +'\t'+ str(timeNow) +'\t'+ '-1\n')
            #file.write('' + count + timeNow + 'left click press\n')                 
    count += 1

def update_frames(dt):
    global x
    x=x+1

@mywindow.event
def on_draw():
    pyglet.gl.glClearColor(0,0,0,0)
    mywindow.clear()
    glColor4f(1,0,0,1)
    drawSquare(x,y)#this draws an opengl square
    fps.draw()# Show FPS


dt = 1/10.0
pyglet.clock.schedule_interval(update_frames,dt)
pyglet.app.run()
```

What can I add to the code in order to obtain an stable frame rate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use something like this instead:

```
import pyglet
from pyglet.gl import *
from collections import OrderedDict
from time import time
from os.path import abspath

class GUI(pyglet.window.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        super(GUI, self).__init__(640,340, caption='Test')

        pyglet.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.alive = True
        self.batches = OrderedDict()
        self.batches['apples'] = pyglet.graphics.Batch()

        self.framerate = 0, time()
        self.count = 0

    def render(self, *args):
        self.clear()

        #glColor4f(1,0,0,1)
        #drawSquare(x,y)

        if time() - self.framerate[1] > 1:
            print('fps:',self.framerate[0])
            self.framerate = 0, time()
        else:
            # Not an optimal way to do it, but it will work.
            self.framerate = self.framerate[0]+1, self.framerate[1]

        self.flip()

    def on_draw(self):
        self.render()

    def on_close(self):
        self.alive = False

    def on_key_press(self, symbol, modkey):
        pass

    def on_key_release(self, symbol, modkey):
        pass

    def on_mouse_release(self, x, y, button, modifiers):
        pass

    def on_mouse_press(self, x, y, button, modifiers):
        self.count += 1
        with open('debug.log', 'w') as fh:
            fh.write(str(count))

    def on_mouse_motion(self, x, y, dx, dy):
        pass

    def on_mouse_drag(self, x, y, dx, dy, buttons, modifiers):
        pass

    def run(self):
        while self.alive:
            event = self.dispatch_events()
            if event:
                print(event)
            self.render()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = GUI()
    pyglet.clock.set_fps_limit(60)
    x.run()
```

For one, this code actually produces 60 FPS,
You get way better control over your application and your main loop.

Secondly, the coding style is perhaps a personal preference but throwing stuff into class objects rather than doing a huge list of functions which you attach to say @window.update etc is more to my liking.. The code looks cleaner.

Give it a go, see if it works.

**Note:** Key here is `event = self.dispatch_events()` which must be called for each iteration, it's what replaces `app.run()`.

## Tie this together with objects and rendering them

```
class House(pyglet.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        self.texture = pyglet.image.load(abspath('./image.png'))
        super(House, self).__init__(self.texture)

        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0
        self.rotation = 0

        self.name = 'house'
        self.anchor = 'center'

    def swap_image(self, image):
        self.texture = pyglet.image.load(abspath(image))
        self.image = self.texture

    def rotate(self, deg):
        self.image.anchor_x = self.image.width / 2
        self.image.anchor_y = self.image.height / 2
        self.rotation = self.rotation+deg
        if self.anchor != 'center':
            self.image.anchor_x = 0
            self.image.anchor_y = 0
        return True

    def click(self):
        print('Clicked:',self.name)

    def work(self, *args):
        pass

    def click_check(self, x, y):
        if x > self.x and x < (self.x + self.width):
            if y > self.y and y < (self.y + self.height):
                return self

    def move(self, x, y):
        if self.moveable:
            self.x += x
            self.y += y

    def _draw(self):
        self.draw()
```

in `GUI()` you'll do:

```
class GUI(pyglet.window.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        super(GUI, self).__init__(640,340, caption='Test')
        ...
        self.house = House()

    def render(self, *args):

        self.house.rotate(1)
        self.house._draw()
```

This should create a "house" (or whatever) and rotate the picture 1 degrees for each render occations, meaning you'll be rotating it 60 degrees a second with a nice flow.

There's more stuff to this than just this, but it's a simplification of what i usually use to squeeze out FPS while still maintaining readable code.. Because graphics get messy quite quickly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As you saig, it produces 60 FPS, so great. But how would you use the GUI class in order to display an animation in it?

Comment: Depends on what kind of animation. Usually you create a new class for an object with its own `_draw()` function that you call from the main GUI class, i'll add some example code.

Comment: @jl.da Forgot to ping you in my previous message.. so here's a ping right now :)

Comment: I should say that I am new to Pyglet. I have created a function with OpenGL commands that draws a simple figure, then the on_draw() function calls it in order to display the figure. How can I use this with your GUI class? 
In addition I would like to know how to use a class with its own `draw()` function, as you suggest. I understand that this way, the program will be more modular, Will this improve the performance too?

Comment: @jl.da It's simple, take the code in your `on_draw()` (except fps.draw()) and add that into my `def render(self, *args)` function. Performance wise I think it will be partly faster for sure, at least in the long run. The code will produce what you're looking for, here take a look at it in a working example all tied togeather: https://gist.github.com/Torxed/a1f3384d4a718c8ad3b7